# How can I check SSL certificates when forwarding HTTPS/curl over a SSH tunnel?

Tags: bash, curl, ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I have several shh tunnels pointing to different "remotes_servers" (different domains) like this:

```
ssh -fN -L local_port:remote_server:remote_port user@gateway
```

So in my local machine `localhost:local_port` points to `remote_server:remote_port`, the issue is that some of `remote_server`s need a custom CA certificate.

When I try to do something like:

```
curl --cacert CA.pem https://localhost:local_port
```

I have an error "no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'localhost'" which is true, because I'm pointing to `localhost` instead of `remote_server`

The connection could be established using `--insecure` in `curl`, `--config http.sslVerify=false` in `git`, etc. I would like to avoid that type of approach.

I would like to find a way to indicate, in the client side, that `localhost:local_port` both, not just `localhost` is the same as `remote_server:remote_port`, I have other ports that point to different `remote servers` always using `localhost`.

Comment: Exactly -- the fact that it's bash is _not relevant to the problem_, making it a generic curl usage question more topical on [unix.se]. I don't think it's _unambiguously_ off-topic here, but I do think there's a fair argument in each direction.

Comment: The client absolutely can control which hostname it requests and checks for during TLS negotiation separate from the name used for the underlying TCP connection -- I added an answer to that effect; is it not showing up for you?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `https://localhost`. Instead, use your remote hostname in the address, and use the `--connect-to` argument, like so:

```
curl \
  --cacert CA.pem \
  --connect-to localhost:local_port \
  https://remote_server:remote_port/
```

That way the name of `remote_server` is specified during the SNI negotiation (letting the server select the correct certificate if it has several to choose from) and validated during TLS certificate verification.

Comment: Thanks, it worked using `--connect-to :remote_port:localhost:local_port`. I would like a more general solution, to use with `git` too, but seems not possible.

Comment: There are some good solutions I could provide offhand for tunneling git-over-SSH (see `ssh -o ProxyJump`; one can set up a `~/.ssh/config` entry and tell git to use a name that invokes it). If this is the raw git wire protocol... honestly, I haven't used that for years; and if it's git-over-https, that's yet another thing (I'd be tempted to set up a local http server that remote-proxies over ssh to the remote https service; that way you don't need to configure git's internal http(s) client at all). But it probably makes sense to ask a question that explains the details of your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your /etc/hosts file so that `remote_server` actually maps to `localhost` (and then point your browser at `https://remote_server:local_port`).

That is, if I update my `/etc/hosts` file so that I have:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain google.com mentos.com
```

And I set up an SSH port forwarding like:

```
ssh -L 8443:google.com:443 -L 8444:mentos.com:443 some.remote.server
```

Then this runs without errors:

```
curl https://google.com:8443
```

As does:

```
curl https://mentos.com:8444
```

Comment: I have different `remote_server` names, all pointing to localhost, the only change is the port. `example1.com` to `localhost:5000`,  `example2.com` to `localhost:5001`

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem. This works fine with different remote server names. I've updated the answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: Needing to update `/etc/hosts` -- a privileged operation -- to run an otherwise-unprivileged command is a pretty heavy lift. I wouldn't consider this an acceptable answer for that reason.

Comment: `/etc/host` has already things like `173.0.0.0 example1.com` because that is used in other part in a proxy, i thought that was not reelevant. We could reach `example1.com` in two different ways locally depends on what we are doing.